# React-Admin AutocompleteInput only uses first 1000 choices

Tags: autocomplete, react-admin

We use `AutocompleteInput` with an static array of more than 1000 choices for relatedPages:

```
   <ArrayInput source="pages">
    <SimpleFormIterator>
      <AutocompleteInput
        source={"id"}
        choices={relatedPages}
      />
    </SimpleFormIterator>
  </ArrayInput>
```

Expected:
We can select one item of all items in our static array.

Actually:
We can only select from the first 1000 items of our static array. This happens with the `SelectInput`, too.

Is this an expected behaviour and is there a way to increase this limit of 1000 choices?

BUG: [7880](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/7880)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a limitation or the AutocompleteInput as it is now (or, more specifically, of the useChoicesContext and useList hooks).

I advise you to open an issue in the react-admin bug tracker about it.